# ¿COMÓ SABER EL VARLOR AUTOINCREMENTAL E INSERTARLO EN UN CICLO EN OTRA TABLA?

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenas tardes y de antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Les comento , tengo un sistema donde se registran los documentos que se reciben, estos documentos son recibidos y registrados por diferentes departamentos, a su vez cada documento se asigna a 1 o n personas para la que lo atiendan.

El dilema es si dos personas estan registrando al mismo tiempo sus respectivos documentos y presionan el botón guardar al mismo tiempo existe el error de que se duplique el ID.

Para una mayor comprensión del problema les ejemplifico:
Son dos tablas, la de DOCUMENTO y la de Persona_asignada.

La tabla documento tiene un campo llave key_documento y otros de descripción,
La tabla Persona_asignada tiene tambien su campo llave llamado key_asigno y además key_documento; esto para lograr la relación de la información entre tablas.

La forma actual en la que obtengo el valor para cada tabla es que una vez que el usuario presiona el botón guardar hago una consulta en la tabla SELECT TOP 1 key_documento order by key_documento desc, y lo mismo para la tabla persona_asignada. Sin embargo si los usuarios dan clic al mismo tiempo se van a duplicar los id y no habrá integridad en la información.

A esto sumemos el caso que un usuario puede pedir se guarde el registo n veces , con la finalidad de que solo modifique los datos necesarios. Entonces si un usuario  quiere duplicar su registro y además otro hace lo mismo , entonces truentan más los ID´S.

Me indicaron que las columnas de llaves las ponga autoincrementables, pero mi pregunta es si un usuario ingresa un registro, el sistema asigna el  key_documento ,¿ yo comó se qué ID asigno para posteriormente tomarlo e insertar ese valor en la tabla persona_asignada es su campo key_asigno.

Quizá se vea simple y digan usa IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_or_view' )  , pero esto indica que toma el último valor asignado indistintamente del usuario, y yo necesito que sea del usuario que hizo  la captura y tiene la sesion activa.

Bueno no se si me explique , espero puedan darme una idea , gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que te ayude esto, en PHP puedes obtener el id auto incremental al insertar una fila en una tabla.

Insertaría primero en la tabla documento y con lastInsertId() te la la id, si la consulta es satisfactoria te da la id de ese registro nuevo, no se que si estas usando el driver pdo para la conexión a sql-server, ejemplo en link.

Espero que te sirva de algo.

Para driver pdo
https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Para actualizar,  tu idea me inspiró en el camino a seguir, cuando se me presento el problema. En mi caso si estaba utilizando SQL Server y encontré que existe esta función                                            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as IdDoctoAutoicremental   básicamente hace lo que me mencionas en tu comentario. En verdad gracias por la idea